# can't add two matricies of the same size together

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, matrix, addition

I'm trying to add two matrices together.  They are both 400x400.  Here's the bit of code that's giving me trouble:

```
    greys = (r+g+b)./3;
    fc = cat(3, r, g, b);
    combined = (greys+fc)./2; <---error occurs here
```

But when my code gets to the greys+fc part, it throws an error.  This error:

> Error using  +
>
> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in imgSimpleFilter (line 36)
>
> ```
>     combined = (greys+fc)./2;
> ```

when I print the number of rows and columns in both the grey and fc matricies, I get 400 for all of the values (which is exactly as I expected, as I am working with a 400x400 image).

Why isn't it letting me add these together?

I have no problems with the line

```
greys = (r+g+b)./3;
```

and that's adding three 400x400 matrices together.  Any ideas?

Comment: your 'fc' matrix is a 400x400x3 matrix, 'greys' is 400x400.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add them because `greys` is 400x400, while `fc` is 400x400x3.

Try typing `size(greys)` and `size(fc)` on the command line, or `whos greys fc` to see it.

If you want to "combine" them by averaging them, you could use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
combined = bsxfun(@plus, greys, fc) ./ 2;
```